# Adding UIViews using GCD

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

In an application I'm developing, I have a horizontal `UIScrollView` that is used as a sort of table view.

Adding the subviews to it blocked the main thread, so I decided to use GCD instead, and create the views in a background thread and add them to the `UIScrollView` instance in the main queue.

The relevant code is this:

```
NSUInteger numberOfItems = [_dataSource numberOfItemsInBandView:self];
CGFloat __block nextX = 0.0;

dispatch_queue_t bgQueue = dispatch_queue_create("bandview", NULL);

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
    dispatch_async(bgQueue, ^{
        UIView *itemView = [_dataSource bandView:self viewForItemAtIndex:i];
        itemView.frame = CGRectMake(nextX, 0, itemView.frame.size.width, itemView.frame.size.height);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
            [_scrollView addSubview:itemView];
            _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(nextX, self.frame.size.height);
        });
        nextX += itemView.frame.size.width;
    });
}

dispatch_release(bgQueue);
```

`_scrollView` is a `UIScrollView` instance (properly initialized).

What I expected is to see the subviews be added to the `UIScrollView` one by one, but instead, what I'm experiencing is that everything runs asynchroniously, and then the scrollbars refreshes with all its subviews added at once (which is not what I expect).

Can anyone spot what I'm missing here?

Comment: I think that what you are doing is ok and the views are created and added to the scroll view very quickly.  You might want to try a test where you wrap your dispatch to main with a dispatch_after were you can specify a delay.  Also, as others suggest, you may want to use a global concurrent queue for your background queue

Answer (score 3):

`UI` changes need to happen on the main thread. Performing `UI` changes in a background thread (async gcd queue) will result in undefined/undesirable behavior as you are seeing. It seems unlikely that adding subviews is the main cause of the problem. The issue likely lies in the way the data is retrieved for the subviews. A solution would be to add all of the subviews then retrieve the data for them asynchronously, and then update them as the operation completes. Also consider not adding views that will not be visible to the user, and add them dynamically as the user scrolls similar to how a `UITableView` works.

Comment: I thought `dispatch_get_main_queue` ran in the main thread. Is that not the case? I added an `NSAssert` to check for it, and it did not fail...

Comment: Ah ya I see that they are being added back on the main thread but it is possible that all, or a large number of your views get queued into the same main run loop cycle and thats why they are appearing at the same time still. If you want a one by one kind of effect, I recommend using animations.

Comment: That's what I think as well (lot of views getting queued into the same run loop cycle). How would using animations work? `addSubview:` is not "animatable"...

Comment: On option I can think of would be to dad all of the visible subviews with an alpha of `0` (or hidden), then anything that takes a while (db or network activity) will run on an separate thread, once the operation completes use another serial queue to call back to main thread to show the view. You will need to wait for the animation to complete in the serial queue by waiting for the animation complete callback.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing worth pointing out is that you have created a serial queue (bandview) to dispatch the UIView creation requests into, but this also means that each creation request will happen in linear order vs being created in the most concurrent fashion possible.  You might try dispatching the creation requests onto one of the global concurrent queues if that's not the desired behavior.

Comment: This is intentional, since I need to accumulate the width of each view, so I can't do it in parallel.